# Design Discussion: Modal React Component with Youtube Player

Tags: reactjs, youtube, redux

I'm after some design advice. I'm building out a React/Redux app that will, amongst other things, play Youtube videos in a modal dialog.

My initial design was to use lifecycle hooks to initialise the Youtube iframe API in the modal's `componentDidMount`. The problem with this approach is that the startup cost for the Youtube player is high - there's a noticeable delay between opening the modal, and the player popping in with the video.

What I need to do is initialise the player just once, and then cue up a different video based on which props are sent to the modal. However, I can't think of a nice, idiomatic design for this model.

Ideas I've had so far:

- Hack around with the modal so that it never unmounts, but just hides based on some prop value.

  - This is the design I had with a previous non-React version of this app, but it feels very hacky, and I'd like to come up with something better.
- Initialise the youtube player when the app loads, and hold the element in the store, passing it down to the modal via props to be rendered.

  - This is recommended against in the [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state)
- Initialise the youtube player at some higher level of the app which is always mounted, but hide it with CSS. On mounting the modal, move the element inside, and move it out again just before unmounting.

  - This is probably my favourite idea so far, it just feels like there might be a better idea out there.

Any thoughts on how to design this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar approach to what you described as the last option (preferred one).
It is called `portal` as far as I can remember.

The basic method is: You make manipulation with element outside of your component in `componentDidMount` (eg. show) and `componentWillUnmount` (eg. hide).

One of the powers of React is it's lifecycle methods. You can create components even without `.render()` method

Examples can be found here
https://github.com/tajo/react-portal

and here
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-music

And there is a great talk about this at React Conf, which completely changed my mind about lifecycle methods.
https://youtu.be/395ou6k6C6k

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looking at the portal library gave me some ideas on how to do this. Unfortunately, they didn't work for me directly, primarily because the Youtube Iframe has all sorts of issues if it ever gets re-rendered. In the end I had to store the element at the document root, and just move it around with CSS to make it _look_ like it was in the modal. Pretty hacky, but the best I can get...